# c# ssh.net PrivateKeyFile Access to Path Denied

Tags: c#, ssh.net

When trying to create a `PrivateKeyFile` object I get the following error:

> Access to the path  is denied.

Here is the code:

```
PrivateKeyFile pk = new PrivateKeyFile(keyfile);
```

I have tried to tweak the Windows security settings (to the point where I set Full Access to Everyone) and that still hasn't solved my issue.

There is no pass phrase for the key.

Anyone run into this?  If so do you have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the file located? some things are protected even with full access.

Comment: It's possible another process has the file open and locked.  It might not be permissions at all.

Comment: The file is in a directory off the root of the c drive.  I can access it from FileZilla and the only thing trying to access it is my sftp app.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found my problem.  The original key was generated on an AIX server. I did check it with PuttyGen, which acknowledged it as an OpenSSL private key.

However, I decided to run the Conversion to OpenSSL anyway.  Once I did that and tried again, it worked and allowed me to connect to the server.

So that seems to be the problem.

Comment: yay for accurate error messages, right?  access to the path denied, indeed!